# Change Vim command to work in MS-Windows? Use make to check python syntax

Tags: python, windows, vim, windows-xp

`:make` provides a list of errors which can be navigated through in order to fix.

The problem is that [this script only works in Unix based OSes.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Python_-_check_syntax_and_run_script)

```
autocmd BufRead *.py set makeprg=python\ -c\ \"import\ py_compile,sys;\ sys.stderr=sys.stdout;\ py_compile.compile(r'%')\"
autocmd BufRead *.py set efm=%C\ %.%#,%A\ \ File\ \"%f\"\\,\ line\ %l%.%#,%Z%[%^\ ]%\\@=%m
```

Anyone could help me make it work or provide the equivalent for Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part to work, you must first add python to your PATH variable.

http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm

python.exe should be placed in:

```
c:\PythonXX\bin
```

But I'm not that sure, check it out before adding that one.